# jQuery multiple selectors but cached in a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to avoid the following:

```
var dynS = $('#dyn-style');
var cssA = $('#css-active');

$('#selectors li').click(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('data-id')){
        case 'first-of-type':
            dynS.empty().text('#target p:first-of-type {color: red;}');
            cssA.empty().text('#target p:first-of-type {color: red;}');
```

Is there any way I could use the cached selector variables and set the text() as the same on both, to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.add` see below,

```
dynS.add(cssA).empty().text('#target p:first-of-type {color: red;}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.add`

```
dynS.add(cssA).empty().text('#target p:first-of-type {color: red;}');
```

Comment: oops beat u by 3 secs :P +1 for same answer >.<